# How to pad zeros in matrix in matlab

Tags: matlab, signal-processing

I have two matrices: `finalEnergy{1,j}(i)` and `finalZC{1,j}(i)`. The `finalEnergy{1,1}(i)` has `1 x 611` elements and `finalZC{1,1}(i)` has 595 elements. I have to pad `finalZC{1,1}(i)` to have 611 elements. how to pad the size of each cell of `finalZC{i,j}` to the size of cells in `finalEnergy{i,j}`. My code is below

```
for j=1:length(finalEnergy)
  for i=1:length(finalEnergy{1,j})
    if(length(finalEnergy{1,j})<length(finalZC{1,j}))

      lenFE=length(finalZC{1,j})-length(finalEnergy{1,j});

      finalEnergy{1,j})(i)=padarray(finalEnergy,lenFE,padding);
    end 
  end
end
```

Comment: Are those always the sizes? If so, why do you have the `if` statement? Or can the sizes be different sometimes?

Comment: it don't have same size always.It varies as j changes

Answer (score 0):

You have a few bugs and implementation errors in your loop, but the idea is right. You do not need to loop over `i` here, if I understand you correctly.

```
for j=1:size(finalEnergy, 2)
    if(numel(finalEnergy{1, j})>numel(finalZC{1, j})) 
        lenFE=length(finalEnergy{1, j})-length(finalZC{1, j});  
        finalZC{1, j}=padarray(finalZC{1, j},[0 lenFE/2], 0);
    end
end
```

There must be a more efficient way to do this. This also assumes that `lenFE` is always an even number, which is correct in your case. I might edit this answer later to put in a more general solution..

Comment: finalEnergy {i ,j } always remains as finalEnergy{1, j } because we have used only one row. In finalEnergy{1, j }(i) i is 1*somevalue row matrix in finalEnergy{1, j }. How could I send mat file for better understanding

Comment: Ok I think I understand you better now, see the updated answer